# Class not found despite importing it

Tags: jakarta-ee

Class could not be found despite importing it in class in android application being built in Android Studio

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
```

What may be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the correct jar file to your classpath. Maybe servlet.jar is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks, solved by adding following line to build.gradle of my servlet   compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

Comment: Cool! So post the solution for other people or accept an answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding following line to build.gradle of my servlet compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'